# R + return a complex type from a function

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I need to return a collection of matrices and associated x, y values for each matrix (ie. a portion of an image, and its x/y location within the original)

I'm trying something like this:

```
getPortions <- function(imgLocation, portionSize, stepSize) {
    require(dplyr)
    require(foreach)
    require(ripa)
    require(jpeg)

    img <- readJPEG(imgLocation) %>% rgb2grey

    prows <- seq(1, nrow(img) - portionSize, by = stepSize)
    pcols <- seq(1, ncol(img) - portionSize, by = stepSize)

    portions <- foreach(r = prows, .combine = rbind) %do% {
        foreach(c = pcols, .combine = rbind) %do% {
            portion <- img[r:(r + portionSize), c:(c + portionSizee)]

            # this doesn't work correctly
            as.data.frame(portion, r, c)
        }
    }

    portions
}
```

... but this gets me a huge data frame.

- I tried converting portion to a vector, as that would be a valid return type from the function (matrix or vector is fine).
- I tried to cbind(portion, r, c) which gave me a similar result as I have now
- I tried one or two other things that I forget, but they didn't have any favourable result

Ideally, I want to get back a data frame with 3 columns. The first column will be the vector/matrix of the portion, and the other 2 columns will contain the row and column locations of the portion.

When I was looking for a solution, I saw that there is a bit of a hack that allows multiple return types, but that's not really a good solution.

Edit> 
Apparently this isn't clear enough. If this were another language (C# for eg.) I'd return a type of IEnumerable>. I don't know how to do that in R.

**Repro**

```
# If necessary
install.packages(c('dplyr', 'foreach', 'doParallel', 'ripa', 'jpeg')) 
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ripa)
library(jpeg)

# copy/paste function here

portions <- getPortions('path/to/image.jpg', 10, 5)
ncol(portions)
[1] 9409
```

The number of columns returned will depend on the image and the portion/step sizes, but either way it's more than 3 and I can't easily extract out the matrix, and r/c values from the data frame.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking at all.

Comment: If you need to return multiple objects, just return a list of those objects; don't try to mash it into a data.frame.  Your example isn't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can't offer any specifics. Try taking out stuff that's not necessary for the question and being clear about what sample input would like and what the desired output for that input would be.

Comment: @MrFlick: I updated with a repro.